# How does it Access appsettings from this c# Class Library Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I saw the sample ASP.NET core Web Api at following website:
https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/dapper-in-aspnet-core/

It uses the dapper for accessing SQL database with 3 class library projects. In the c# class library project named "Dapper.Infrasstructure", the ProductRepository.cs program obtains the SQL connection string from appsettings.cshtml with code shown in CODE SEGMENT 1. It also uses IServiceCollection for registering services in setup.cs (see CODE SEGMENT 2). The library project includes three packages (See CODE SEGMENT 3).

Since there is no appsettings file in any class library.  how does it access the settings that is in the main project "Dapper.WebApi"? The program was build with ASP.NET core 3.1.  I compiled it using .NET 5.  It wors just fine. I also checked the content of its setup.cs file (see CODE SEGMENT 4) and program.cs file (see CODE SEGMENT 5).

### I tried to use the similar implementation method in an ASP.NET core MVC program.  It could not get the SQL connection string from appsettings contained in the main web app from the C# class library project. What makes the accessing appsettings possible in Web API but not from MVC web app?

### CODE SEGMENT 1

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public ProductRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public async Task<int> AddAsync(Product entity)
    {
        entity.AddedOn = DateTime.Now;
        var sql = "Insert into Products (Name,Description,Barcode,Rate,AddedOn) VALUES (@Name,@Description,@Barcode,@Rate,@AddedOn)";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, entity);
            return result;
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

---

### CODE SEGMENT 2

```
using Dapper.Application.Interfaces;
using Dapper.Infrastructure.Repository;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Dapper.Infrastructure
{
    public static class ServiceRegistration
    {
        public static void AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### CODE SEGMENT 3

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

### CODE SEGMENT 4

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapper.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace Dapper.WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddInfrastructure();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\Dapper.WebApi.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "Dapper - WebApi",
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            #region Swagger
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CleanArchitecture.WebApi");
            });
            #endregion
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

### CODE SEGMENT 5

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Dapper.WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, does the code segment 1,2,3 exist in `Dapper.Infrastructure` and code segment 4,5 exist in `Dapper.WebApi`? Also does the appsettings.json exist in `Dapper.Infrastructure` ?

Comment: @Rena:  You are correct.  The code segments 1,2 & 3 are in the class library:  Dapper.infrastructure and code segments 4 & 5 are in Dapper.WebApi.  When viewing the code:  The Dapper.WebApi project has project level reference to Dapper.Infrastructure.

Comment: @Rena:  Do you have additional questions or suggestions about my question?

Comment: Hi @bedrock, does the appsettings.json exist in `Dapper.Infrastructure`?

Comment: No. there is no appsettings.json file in Dapper.Infrastruction project.  I did file search for entire solution and the results showed that file exists in Dapp.webapi project.

Comment: How do you invoke method in ProductRepository? I call it in web api project and it can get the connection string successfully.

Comment: When I tested the app, I used the URL: https://localhost:44305/api/Product.  It access the constructor of ProductRepository.cs:  "public ProductRepository (IConfiguration configuration)".  I also tested with https://localhost:44305/swagger and select an API from its UI.  It also invoked the ProductRepository the same way.    Among three class library projects in this app, there are chained dependencies: "Dapper.Infrastructure" -> "Dapper.Application" -> "Dapper.Core".  But none of them has dependency on main Dapper.WebApi project.  How does class library project get config settings?

Comment: I think they need add reference with Web api project otherwise IConfiguration cannot find the appsettings.json.

Comment: @Rena: Dapper.WebApi already has the reference to Dapper.Infrastructure project. In Dapper.Infrasture project, we won't be able to add reference to Dapper.WebApi because it will cause the circular reference, which will cause errors when build/compile the solution. The fact is that the app is working fine without addtional reference. We are back to the original question: how does it work right now.  Any other suggestions?